# How to align icon inserted with :before method?

Tags: html, css

How can I vertically align icon inserted using :before method?

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="button submit">
  <a class="submit check_car_search" href="#" >Some Text</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button a{
    background: none;
    background-color: #32BBE7;
    text-indent:1px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.button a:hover{
    background-color: #2597F0;
}


.button a:before {
    content:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png);
    position: relative
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1z83tc1o/

How Can I align vertically icon relative to the text?

Comment: i did not understand what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `background` and set is size (width, height), Then you can use `vertical-align`.

**CSS**

```
.button a:before {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content:"";
    background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png) no-repeat center center;
    margin-right: 20px; // Optional

}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/1z83tc1o/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You use `background` and `absolute position` the icon to perfectly vertical align in the middle.

```
.button a:before {
    content: " ";
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 18px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -8px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

Here is the example : https://jsfiddle.net/1z83tc1o/3/